# iOS 11 UIImagePickerController after selection cancel button bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ios11

I'm using UIImagePickerController to select the photo and crop image.

This is the same situation as seen at
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88286

Here is my code:

```
- (void) onTest:(UIButton *)btn {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [picker setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

This is view layer. I did not add this UIView.
I can't press the cancel button and I can't zoom in/out.

There is no problem with iOS 10. I only have a problem with iOS 11.

Comment: Have you tried bringSubViewToFront: selector to bring it to front of this view blocking touch ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I have a good idea to address this issue.

Set the controller (from which you show the `UIImagePickerController`) as the delegate for the `UIImagePickerController`, then conforms the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` since `UIImagePickerController` is the subclass of `UINavigationController`, then implement the method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
  if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue < 11) {
    return;
  }
  if ([viewController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"PUPhotoPickerHostViewController")]) {
    weakify(viewController);
    [viewController.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
      if (obj.frame.size.width < 42 && FLOAT_EQUAL(obj.frame.size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)) {
        strongify(viewController);
        [viewController.view sendSubviewToBack:obj];
        *stop = YES;
      }
    }];
  }
}
```

Comment: What's weakify, strongify and FLOAT_EQUAL? I tried your solution but xcode show error Implicit declaration of function '...' is invalid in C99

Comment: weakController ， FLOAT_EQUAL is to compare two float value

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)addPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```

Use this delegate :-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: PUPhotoPickerHostViewController is photo crop viewController. this viewController has two buttons. cancel button and choose button. cancel button not work.. PUPhotoPickerHostViewController's cancel button dosen't matter delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open Photo library:

```
        UIImagePickerController *pickerView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        pickerView.allowsEditing = YES;
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        [pickerView setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:pickerView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And use this delegate to get the cropped image to your view controller:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIImage *image = chosenImage;
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```